# Showing an uncountable set is equivalent to the positive set of integers

Tags: general-topology

Show that the set $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty}\left\{1,0\right\}$ is equivalent to the set of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, and explain why this shows it is uncountable.

Proof: We want a function that is a bijection from $\prod_{i = 1}^{\infty}\left\{1,0\right\}$ to the set of subsets of $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$. Let $$y = \left\{y_i\right\}_{i = 1}^{\infty} \in  \prod_{i = 1}^{\infty}\left\{1,0\right\}$$ Define $f(y) = \left\{i\in \mathbb{Z}^{+}: y_i = 1\right\}$

Now I need to show that the function is one to one and onto, can anyone lend me some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the usual proof that a function one-to-one and onto made a little bit fancier because the sets are unusual.

Show that $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$ by noting that two sets are equal if and only if they have the same elements, and thus correspond to the same collection of non-zero entries.

Show that $f$ is onto by describing a (the) function $g$ such that $f(g(S)) = S$.

Alternatively, to show that $f$ is one-to-one, use the same $g$ and show that $g(f(x)) = x$.

---

**Injectivity:** suppose that $f(x) = f(y):=S$.  That is, $S = \{i:y_i = 1\} = \{i:x_i = 1\}$.  Thus, for all $i \in S$ (and only for those $i$), $x_i = y_i = 1$.  Since for all $i$ we have $x_i,y_i \in \{0,1\}$, we may further conclude that for all $i \notin S$, $x_i = y_i = 0$.

Thus, we conclude that $x_i = y_i$ for all $i$, which is to say that $x = y$.

**Surjectivity:** given a set $S \subset \Bbb Z^+$, define $x$ by
$$
x_i =
\begin{cases}
1 & i \in S\\
0 & i \notin S
\end{cases}
$$
we note that $x \in \prod_{\Bbb Z^+} \{1,0\}$ and that $f(x) = S$.

Comment: I know that, but I am not sure how to specifically prove my function is a bijection

Comment: Bijection *means* one to one and onto. This specifically answers your question.

Comment: Or maybe you mean that your stuck on the specifics of the steps- which part are you having trouble with? Can you figure out what to write for showing "$f$ is one to one"?

Comment: Yes, I am stuck on the specific steps of showing the injection and surjection part of the function I defined